Adding users temporarily to Active Directory groups using PHP
I am trying to create a PHP script which will be run via a Linux (Debian) CLI using PHP 7.4. This script is trying to add a user in Active Directory to a group and that part work.
<?php

$ldaphost = 'ldaps://domain.uk';
$ldapport = 636;

putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never');

$ds = ldap_connect($ldaphost, $ldapport) or die("Could not connect to $ldaphost");
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

if ($ds) {
    
    $username = "cn=user1,ou=test,dc=domain,dc=uk";
    $upasswd = "XXXXXXX";

    $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ds, $username, $upasswd);

        $groupDN = 'cn=temp-access,ou=test,dc=domain,dc=uk';
    $userDN = 'cn=user1,ou=test,dc=domain,dc=uk';

     $entry = ['member' => $userDN];
     ldap_modify($ds, $groupDN, $entry);

}

What I actually need the script to do is also set the TTL on the groupDN to support temporary group membership. However, when setting the $groupDN variable to the following string I get an error.
$groupDN = '<ttl=1866,cn=temp-access,ou=test,dc=domain,dc=uk>'; 
PHP Warning:  ldap_modify(): Modify: Invalid DN syntax
According to the following post it is possible to achieve in Python.
Add User To an Active Directory Group temporarily in Python
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

What does the error tell you: "Invalid DN syntax"? It says you're giving it an invalid syntax. Now look at your current $groupDN. It's basically just entry=value, entry=value, etc. Then look at the one that's giving you the error. It's surrounded by < ... >. Can you guess what the problem is now?

Thank you for commenting on my issue. The provided link to the python example shows the use of <...> to suround the DN when providing a TTL. I tried removing them and still providing the TTL parameter but it then is unable to find the DN thinking it is part of the group name.

What version of Active Directory domain controller do you have? The <ttl,dn> with brackets appears to be correct – certainly not the first time AD has used that kind of syntax for DN attributes in its proprietary extensions – but support for it is definitely version-specific and I faintly remember it might have only been added in Srv2019 or something along those lines.

Thank you, we are running SRV2019 and I can confirm that the -MemberTimeToLive parameter when set using powershell on joining users to groups functions as expected. The error to me appears to be a PHP error rather than a response from AD. I wonder if PHP validates what it thinks are supported characters.

I looked at this again, and... Aren't you applying this syntax to the wrong DN?

You are right, I applied it to the userDN and it works as expected. Thank you so much.

The TTL needs to be set on the userDN and not the groupDN.
$userDN = '<ttl=1866,cn=user1,ou=test,dc=domain,dc=uk>';
Thank you, @grawity_u1686.
